# Why is the speed of the parts of the LU-decomposition so different?

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, matrix, performance

I know that an easy way to solve the matrix problem
$$A\cdot x=b$$
is the LU decomposition
$$\begin{split}
L,\,U&=\text{lu}(A)\\
y&=\text{solve}(L,\,b)\\
x&=\text{solve}(U,\,y)
\end{split}$$
Thus I implemented the following code in matlab:

```
r_num = 10000;
r_rounds = 10000;

A = -30*sparse(diag(ones(r_num,1),0))+16*sparse(diag(ones(r_num-1,1),1))+16*sparse(diag(ones(r_num-1,1),-1))-sparse(diag(ones(r_num-2,1),-2))-sparse(diag(ones(r_num-2,1),2));

b = rand(r_num,1);

tic;
for i = 1:r_rounds
    c1 = A\b;
end
toc;

tic;
[L, U] = lu(A);
for i = 1:r_rounds
    y = L\b;

end
toc;
tic;
for i = 1:r_rounds
    c2 = U\y;
end
toc;
```

I already know that $A\setminus b$ is doing the LU-decomposition in the background, but I still was interested in the result. Now my script returned that the calculation of $L\setminus b$ was nearly as expensive as the direct calculation $A\setminus b$, while the calculation of $U\setminus y$ was extremely fast. But where does the difference come from? Or is my measurement method flawed?

When timing the LU-decomposition separately, I get

```
A\b
Elapsed time is 13.380155 seconds.
lu(A)
Elapsed time is 0.002662 seconds.
y=L\b
Elapsed time is 10.557989 seconds.
c2=U\y
Elapsed time is 1.229101 seconds.
```

The reason for timing the LU-decomposition separately (outside of the loop) is because for my later application I will have to deal with a constant $A$, but a large amount of changing $b$-values. Thus I try to keep the amount of elements in the loop as low as possible.

Comment: It can be expected that the forward substitution will be faster than the back substitution, due to [this paper](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/uploads/cels/papers/P1658.pdf). Not sure how that applies to Matlab though.

Comment: @ChristianClason: I added a timing round with separate timing for the decomposition, it does not change the result (the decomposition is quite fast). The cholesky decomposition is not possible, after my target matrix (what I want to benchmark for) is not symmetric anymore.

Comment: @jik Doesn't Matlab use a column compressed sparse format, which would reverse that result? That would fit with the idea that it's the U solve which has fewer cache misses and is faster here.

Comment: @origimbo It apparently doesn't matter here, but anyway: I don't think that using CSC instead of CSR is an improvement for the backward substitution. Although you could process each column from top to bottom, the column-wise traversal completely destroys the per-row aggregated access to the solution vector (or right hand side if you modify it in-place). For some "nice" matrices you might get away with it, but I think using CSR (with the modification proposed in the paper) is generally faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't forget to also time the LU decomposition in a loop! Otherwise it's not really a fair comparison. If I do that, I get the following timings:

```
A\b:   Elapsed time is 10.294272 seconds.
lu(A): Elapsed time is 26.675160 seconds.
L\b:   Elapsed time is 9.934748 seconds.
U\y:   Elapsed time is 1.469325 seconds.
```

You can see that both `A\b` and `lu(A)` are of the same order of magnitude, which is expected. Since the matrix in this example is in fact symmetric, you'd also expect that Matlab will *not* do an LU decomposition. Replacing `lu` by `chol` gives a timing of `10.067633 seconds` -- very close to Matlab's backslash.

(In fact, you can ask Matlab what it's doing by setting `spparms('spumoni',2)`, which will tell you on `A\b`:

```
sp\: bandwidth = 2+1+2.
sp\: is A diagonal? no.
sp\: is band density (1) > bandden (0.5) to try banded solver? yes.
sp\: is LAPACK's banded solver successful? yes.
```

So it's in fact using a specialized solver.)

To see why `L\b` is so much slower than `U\y`, it's instructive to look at the sparsity pattern of both via `spy`:

[image: sparsity pattern of L]
[image: sparsity pattern of U]

You can see that `L` has a much more complicated sparsity pattern than `U` (which is upper tridiagonal, corresponding to the sparsity pattern of `A`), so the corresponding substitution step will be much slower. In fact, asking Matlab again what it's doing on `L\b`:

```
sp\: bandwidth = 2+1+707.
sp\: is A diagonal? no.
sp\: is band density (0.0043793) > bandden (0.5) to try banded solver? no.
sp\: is A triangular? no.
sp\: is A morally triangular? yes.
sp\: permute and solve.
```

So you see that extra work is being done here.

Comment: Why is the matrix $L$ shown as upper-triangular? Is it in fact $L^T$? Also, assuming that $A$ is symmetric positive-definite, then it has a unique decomposition $A = L L^T$, so the factors $L$ and $U$ should have the same sparsity pattern (up to the transposition).

Comment: @jlk Good question, but this is what the OP's code produces. (Note that `lu`, different than `chol`, produces a *permuted* lower triangular matrix. The documentation explicitly states `Return value L is a product of lower triangular and permutation matrices.`)

Comment: Hmm, so a permuted triangular matrix is generally not triangular and `L\b` is probably doing yet another factorization. Still, I don't see why the pattern of `U` is nearly diagonal...

Comment: @jlk Good point! (The pattern of `U` -- is derived from `A`, which is pentadiagonal; that's a consequence of how LU decomposition is derived from Gaussian elimination.)

Comment: If you want you can explicitly do the permutation by calling `[L,U,P]=lu(A); y=L\(P*b); x=U\y;` -- here, `L` will in fact be lower tridiagonal.